# Center check boxes with css in cfml page

Tags: html, css, checkbox, responsive-design

I'm having a really basic issue with css. It won't let me centre my checkboxes in the middle of the page. The checkboxes are actually coldfusion, but should work the same.

myform.cfml:

```css
.myform {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.checkboxes {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="myform">
  <cfform action="landing.cfml" method="post">

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <cfoutput query="animals">

        <input type="checkbox" name="myDataList" value="#animals#" <cfif listFind(selectedAnimals, animalid)></cfif>> #animalname# <br />
      </cfoutput>
    </div>

    <cfinput type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit">
  </cfform>
</div>
```

I coloured the background of the checkboxes blue to see how it lies. It spreads across the whole screen. `margin: auto;` or `margin: 0 auto;` make no difference. It also doesn't matter if the `margin: auto;` is in the .myform or the .checkboxes, it still doesn't work. If I change it to `margin-left: 30rem; margin-right:30rem;` it moves, but I can't have an absolute positioning.

Everything I have read says to use `margin: auto;` and it should position the div in the centre horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `display: flex;` on the parent with `justify-content: center;`

```css
.myform {
  position: relative;
  right: 0; /* Fill in a positive value here, to push to left */
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkboxes {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="myform">
  <cfform action="landing.cfml" method="post">

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <cfoutput query="toolIds">

        <input type="checkbox" name="myDataList" value="#toolid#" <cfif listFind(selectedTools, toolid)></cfif>> #toolname# <br />
      </cfoutput>
    </div>

    <cfinput type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit">
  </cfform>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that works! I have another question - if I want it to sit slightly to the left, is there any way to do that? I've put it as margin-left: -200px; is that a good way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, since you already have `position: relative;` you can set a value for `right` on the parent which will push it left depending on how high the value is. Using negative margin is not all bad, but I try to avoid it if I can. See my edits w/ the CSS I added and the note.